# OAuth with Azure Active Directory: Azure AD returns incorrect value for the State parameter after denying admin-consent scopes

Tags: azure-active-directory

During OAuth interaction with Azure AD, it appears that Azure returns incorrect value for the State parameter after users deny grant for admin-consent scopes.

When constructing the URL for requesting authorization code from Azure AD via the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`, let say I specify the State parameter as `a+b`. 
Then url encoding the State parameter value to `a%2Bb` and then put in the URL for requesting authorization code from Azure AD

If the request specifies scopes that require administrator consent and have not be granted in the past, Azure returns the following page as expected:

[image: App requires administrator consent]

I was trying to verify my application logic for handling errors returning from Azure. So I denied this consent by clicking the `Return to the application without granting consent` link. After that, Azure expectedly returned an error response to my app's redirect URI. Azure populated the data in the HTTP body as follows:

[image: Error response after denying admin-consent scopes]

Azure populated the State parameter value as `a%252bb`. This is not correct.  The expected value should be `a%2Bb` - i.e. same as the value specified earlier when calling the Azure authorization code request endpoint as described earlier.  It looks like Azure somehow performed a double URL encoding - in other words, encoding an already url-encoded State parameter, changing `a%2Bb` to `a%252bb`. (`%` was encoded to `%25`. In addition it is strange that `B` somehow became `b`)

It appears that Azure has this issue in the code path for handling users clicking the `Return to the application without granting consent` link for denying admin-consent scopes. For the other scenario of users denying user-consent scopes, it appears that Azure does NOT have this issue. Azure returns a proper value for the State parameter as illustrated as follows:

[image: Error response after denying user-consent scopes]

Comment: Not able to reproduce this issue using the request like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/adfei.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=token+id_token&client_id=57336bd5-a80f-4b48-a29a-07fdea6ef91e&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=openid+Directory.Read.All&state=a+b&nonce=123&response_mode=form_post`. You may share the exact request to help lookup this issue.

Comment: Looks like the URL you tried is for _implicit grant flow_ (`response_type=token+id_token`). I used the _authorization code flow_ (`response_type=id_token+code`) when I saw this issue.  
  
This is the encoded URL I used for requesting authorization code from Azure AD:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce_value}&response_type=id_token%20code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20offline_access%20Group.ReadWrite.All&state=a%2Bb`

Comment: I am also test using the request above, however still failed to reproduce this issue. Here is the request for your reference:`https://login.microsoftonline.com/adfei.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_mode=form_post&nonce=abc&response_type=id_token code&client_id=57336bd5-a80f-4b48-a29a-07fdea6ef91e&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=openid email profile offline_access Group.ReadWrite.All&state=a%2Bb`. Whatever I pass the state with `a+b` or `a%2Bb`, it return the correct value. The only difference is the value is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again today. Looks like Microsoft has just removed the `Return to the application without granting consent` link. So the issue mentioned in this post earlier no longer exists.

[image: You can't access this application page]